# Sorting a list of dictionaries based on a value

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I am having trouble trying to sort a list of dictionaries based on a value matching a string. Here's an example:

```
test = [{'username': "1", "password": "test1"},
        {"username": "3", "password": "test2"},
        {"username": "5", "password": "test3"}]
```

I would like to sort this dictionary based on password = test3, so it would look like:

```
test = [{"username": "5", "password": "test3"},
        {'username': "1", "password": "test1"},
        {"username": "3", "password": "test2"}]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `test.sort(key=lambda x: x['password'] != 'test3')`

Comment: So the dict(s) with `d['password'] == 'test3'` has to come first, with the remaining dicts in any arbitrary order?

Comment: @chepner Yes exactly

Comment: @StardustGogeta that works! Thank you!

Comment: Not really a duplicate, since we're sorting on a value *derived* from the value, not the value itself. (There may be a better duplicate, though.)

Comment: @King your question is incomplete. In a set of items an order must be defined among all items. In your example however, The only order you point out is `test3` and all the other items. I recommend to explain more about the expected outcome. The question as it stands simply does not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test.sort(key=lambda x: x['password'] != 'test3')
```

The [`.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method for lists allows you to use an arbitrary `key` function. In this case, we use a function that returns `False` (which equals 0) if the `'password'` field equals `'test3'`.